# Posting string from Winforms to MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I have a winform app that is collection info from the users system and passing that data to my MVC app. My winform posts the data like so:

```
public void postTheData(string theData)
        {
            string dataToSend = "ThePostedData=" + theData; 
            var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSend);

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:52212/Licensing");
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
            req.Method = "POST";

            using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
            }

            // -- execute request and get response
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {MessageBox.Show("Posted!");}
               // Console.WriteLine("Hooray!");

        }
```

My MVC application has a controller called "LicensingController", on which I have:

```
 public class LicensingController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        //HandlePostedData();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void ProcessLicensing(string thePostedData)
    {
        //ViewData["PostedData"] = "This Fired!";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/file.txt"), thePostedData + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        //return View();
    }
```

The HTTP post appears go correctly as far as I can tell, and I get the HTTPStatusCode.OK response.  But the file.txt never gets written to.

This is my first foray into ASP.Net MVC, and what I am having trouble understanding is how does the POST action "wire" to the "ProcessLicensing" method of the controler for the URI "localhost/Licensing/"???  In other words I don't know how to direct my posted data to the particular method I need, if that makes sense.

If I create a view, "Licensing" on which I have:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessLicensing", "Licensing", FormMethod.Post))
       { %>
       <%= Html.TextBox("ThePostedData", "DemoData")  %>
       Click to do a post back <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

       <%} %>
```

This does write "Demo Data" to the text file (with the date and time), so it seems like the problem is in the "Form Name"??? I dunno.. I'm lost.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Like I said at the bottom of my post, that does work.

Comment: make sure you `UrlEncode` everything after the `=` sign: `string dataToSend = "ThePostedData=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(theData);`

Answer (score 1):

You posting to your index page:    `@"http://localhost:52212/Licensing"`

You should be posting to `@"http://localhost:52212/Licensing/ProcessLicensing"`